Modify a generalized patch blending to match boundary bitangents.
Background
I have developed the following scheme:
You are given $k$ parametric curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$ sch that their endpoints are connected into a contiguous loop.
You will create an associated planar regular k-polygon.
Given an edge $e_i$ of the polygon and a point $p$ inside of it, let $h_i(p)$ be the orthogonal distance from $p$ to $e_i$.
Define then the weight function:
$$w_i(p) = \prod_{k=0; k \neq i}^{n-1} \frac{h_k(p)}{h_i(p) + h_k(p)}$$
That is, for each edge in the triangle, grab the orthogonal distance from the edge to the point, and the distance to the active edge, and take the fraction of the distance to the other edge of the sum of the two distances. Then take the product of all such fractions.
This function has the following properties:

By construction it is 1 over the active edge and 0 on the other edges.
All values are positive.
We are going to claim that $\frac{0}{0} = 1$ for the purposes of having a defined value at the vertices. i.e. $w_i(v_i) = w_i(v_{i+1}) = 1$.

Then we will define the blending weights:
$$\lambda_i = \frac{w_j(p)}{\sum_{i=0} w_j(p)}$$
By construction this is a convex combination since necessarily $\sum \lambda_j = 1$ with $0 \leq \lambda_j \leq 1$ for any $j$.
Additionally we will define the weight $s_i$ such that
$$s_i(p) = \frac{\|proj(p, e_i)\ - v_{1}\|}{\|e_i\|}$$
i.e. the relative distance of the projection of $p$ onto the edge $e_i$
Then we will define a parametric surface as:
$$ S(p) = \sum^{n-1}_{i=0} \lambda_i C_i(s_i) $$
This results in the following geometry for a pentagon of parabolas:

I.e. the input were the green parabolas and the output the yellow dots.
Actual question
The above lacks tangent information. I would like to modify this scheme such that at the boundary we can specify bitangential/normal information.
Basically, if one grabs the directional derivative in the direction orthogonal to the boundary at the boundary, then the result should match the prescribed tangent.
More technically, assume that in addition to the $k$ curves $C_i$, you are given $k$ parametric functions $B_i$ that return a bitangent to the curves.
Then on the surface $S$ assume that $p_b$ is a point at the boundary. Assume that $d$ is a direction in the tangent plane of $S$ at $p_b$ such that if $t$ is the tangent of the boundary at $p_b$ then $d \cdot t = 0$. I want to make it so that $d = B_i(u)$ where $p_b = C_i(u)$.
A different way to explain it is that I want to extend the behaviour of a bicubic hermite spline such that the surface matches the prescribed boundary conditions.
Is there something I can do?
